# benutzen require dative or accusative case?

Tags: grammatical-case

Writing a piece of German,  using the verb benutzen. Does the verb verb benutzen require dative case?

Looked the verb up in Duden dictionary but cannot work it out.

Comment: Which Duden. The online Duden has several examples which should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synonym verbs [benutzen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/benutzen) (preferred in Germany) and [benützen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ben%C3%BCtzen) (preferred in Austria and Switzerland) both require an object in accusative case.

The already linked online dictionary Wiktionary is often a better resource than Duden. The entry for [benützen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ben%C3%BCtzen) has only one example:

> Auf dem Laptop benütze ich **das Betriebssystem** eines bekannten Herstellers.

It already shows, that the object ***das** Betriebssystem* is in accusative case (if it was dative case, it would have been ***dem** Betriebssystem*)

But the entry for [benutzen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/benutzen) lists even more examples, among them are these which all clearly indicate accusative case:

> Auf dem Laptop benutze ich ***das** Betriebssystem* eines bekannten Herstellers.
> Siehst du nicht, dass er ***dich*** nur benutzt!
> Darf ich mal ***Ihre** Toilette<sup>1</sup>* benutzen?

(Dative object would be: *dir* and *Ihrer Toilette*)

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>off-topic, but still good to know:</sub>
<sub>In houses and apartments in English speaking countries you often find the toilet in the bathroom. That's why you ask for the bathroom when you need to use the toilet in English. But in German speaking countries the toilet is very often located in a separate small room, so that there is no toilet in the bathroom. In German we use the same words for the toilet and the room in which it is, and this words are *WC* (which derives from English *Water Closet* but that's widely forgotten here) and *Toilette.* As a consequence, when you ask for the *Badezimmer* (= bathroom) in a German speaking country, and the host tells you the way to it, you have a high chance to land in a room with a washbasin and a bathtube or a shower but without a toilet. So, you better ask for a *Toilette* instead.</sub>

Comment: It's a good idea to have several dictionaries bookmarked, especially if you're a learner. In addition to German Wiktionary I use English Wiktionary, DWDS and occasionally a few others. Most English dictionaries include a label (tr./intr.) for valence, but this seems less common in German dictionaries and one must often resort to deducing it from examples as you describe. I imagine this is because German has many more possible valences and you shouldn't have to be an expert in grammar to understand a dictionary entry.

Comment: In English, 'toilet' can mean either the actual fixture or the room where it's located, but this can be regional. If you want to be absolutely specific then 'toilet bowl' is the most common phrase.